# Is there a more pythonic way to nest conditional statements for filling a new column in a pandas df?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nested-if

I am new to pandas and python, I searched but couldn't find exactly my problem.  I am trying to find the best way to fill a new column in a pandas data frame 'Sample Location', based on the contents of another column, 'NO', to bin them into defined collections.

The first problem is:

```
        if TestLocation == 'LH Duct': 
            df['Sample Location'] = df.apply(
                lambda x: samplePoint(x['NO']),
                axis=1
            )
```

I am not sure is formed correctly as my dataframe is getting kind of jumbled up.

Second question - Is there a more pythonic way of doing this check:

```
def samplePoint(n):
    if n <= 15:
        v = 'P1 S1'
    elif n >= 20 & n <= 35:
        v = 'P1 S2'
    elif n >= 40 & n <= 55:
        v = 'P1 S3'
    elif n >= 60 & n <= 75:
        v = 'P1 S4'
    elif n >= 80 & n <= 95:
        v = 'P1 S5'
    elif n >= 100 & n <= 115:
        v = 'P1 S6'
    elif n >= 150 & n <= 165:
        v = 'P2 S1'
    elif n >= 170 & n <= 185:
        v = 'P2 S2'
    elif n >= 190 & n <= 205:
        v = 'P2 S3'
    elif n >= 210 & n <= 225:
        v = 'P2 S4'
    elif n >= 230 & n <= 245:
        v = 'P2 S5'
    elif n >= 250 & n <= 265:
        v = 'P2 S6'
    else:
        v = 'null'
    return v
```

I thought the whole thing could/should be done as an apply/lambda but I got a little lost. If someone could explain this or send me a good link I would be eternally grateful!

Comment: Have a look maybe using a list of dicts where you define a low and high value for v descriptor, like: ‘score = [{“low”=0, “high”=15, “v”=“p1 s1”}, {“low”=20, “high”=35, “v”=“p1 s2”},]’. Now when you get a score n you can look in the list which dict to be selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly the value of v_code can be calculated, otherwise I would put the options in a list of dicts and I write the function `samplePoint` as follows:

```
samples = [
    {'range': (0, 15),
     'v_code': 'P1 S1'},
    {'range': (20, 35),
     'v_code': 'P1 S3'},
    {'range': (60, 75),
     'v_code': 'P1 S4'},
    {'range': (80, 95),
     'v_code': 'P1 S5'},
    {'range': (100, 115),
     'v_code': 'P1 S6'},
    {'range': (150, 165),
     'v_code': 'P2 S1'},
    {'range': (170, 185),
     'v_code': 'P2 S2'},
    {'range': (190, 205),
     'v_code': 'P2 S3'},
    {'range': (210, 225),
     'v_code': 'P2 S4'},
    {'range': (230, 245),
     'v_code': 'P2 S5'},
    {'range': (250, 265),
     'v_code': 'P2 S6'},
]


def samplepoint(n):
    for sample in samples:
        if sample['range'][0] <= n <= sample['range'][1]:
            return sample['v_code']

    return 'null'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(samplepoint(10))
```

also renaming `samplePoint` to `samplepoint` as per Python naming convention. To make the module less cluttered you can import the list `samples` from a config file where you keep all your constants and settings. Thus

```
from my_config import samples

def samplepoint(n):
    for sample in samples:
        if sample['range'][0] <= n <= sample['range'][1]:
            return sample['v_code']

    return 'null'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(samplepoint(100))
```

where the file `my_config.py` is

```
samples = [
    {'range': (0, 15),
     'v_code': 'P1 S1'},
    {'range': (20, 35),
     'v_code': 'P1 S3'},
    {'range': (60, 75),
     'v_code': 'P1 S4'},
    {'range': (80, 95),
     'v_code': 'P1 S5'},
    {'range': (100, 115),
     'v_code': 'P1 S6'},
    {'range': (150, 165),
     'v_code': 'P2 S1'},
    {'range': (170, 185),
     'v_code': 'P2 S2'},
    {'range': (190, 205),
     'v_code': 'P2 S3'},
    {'range': (210, 225),
     'v_code': 'P2 S4'},
    {'range': (230, 245),
     'v_code': 'P2 S5'},
    {'range': (250, 265),
     'v_code': 'P2 S6'},
]
```

Comment: Thank you, Bruno... How would I need to manage the external my_config.py file?  Just save it in the same directory as the main.py script?  Or would I have to do something like when you install a python package like matplotlib?

Comment: Just write another python file with the name my_config.py in the same directory as your main.py.

Answer (score 0):

Try built-in [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) method, just example assuming `x` is dataframe and `NO` column You are working on:

```
pd.cut(x['NO'], bins=[15,25,35,40], right=True, labels=False)
```

Adjust bins and edges / alligment to Your needs.

Comment: Thank you @ipj.  I will read up on this built-in method.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
elif n >= 20 & n <= 35:
```

=>

```
elif 20 <= n <= 35:
```

Comment: Thank you @Schiz, that is more pythonic!